# Issue running purrr::possible for error recovery inside ~ tibble

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

I was working through an example from the Hadley Wickham's "The Joy of Functional Programming (for Data Science)" (available on youtube) lecture on purrr and wanted to add in error-recovery using `possibly()` to handle any zip files that fail to be read.

A bit of his code;

`paths <- dir_ls("NSFopen_Alldata/", glob= ".zip")`

`files<- map_dfr(paths, ~ tibble(path=.x, files= unzip(.x, list = TRUE)$Name))`

Adding error recovery with `possibly()`;

`unzip_safe <- possibly(.f= unzip, otherwise = NA)`

`files<- map_dfr(paths, ~ tibble(path=.x, files= unzip_safe(.x, list = TRUE)$Name))`

I get the following error: `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.

Is this because `possibly` is in a tibble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files that fail return an `NA` and you are trying to extract `$Name` from it which returns an error. See

```
NA$NAme
```

> Error in NA$NAme : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Extract `$Name` from the successful files in `possibly` itself. Try :

```
library(purrr)
unzip_safe <- possibly(.f= ~unzip(., list = TRUE)$Name, otherwise = NA)
files <- map_dfr(paths, ~ tibble(path=.x, files = unzip_safe(.x))
```